# php object property NULL in required page

Tags: php, require-once

Why does this work:

```
echo $session->name;
require_once('test.php');
//echos the name then loads the required page
```

But

```
var_dump($session->name);
```

in the code of test.php returns NULL.

I thought `require_once` pretty much plops all the code from the required page into the spot I told it to.

**EDIT**

$session instance is created before the require, outside of test.php. If I create a new instance of $session inside test.php it works. Glad it works but this still doesnt make sense to me, can anyone explain?

Comment: is the var_dump the only thing in test.php?

Comment: and what does var_dump($session) return ?

Comment: No there is other code that runs fine in `test.php`. `var_dump($session)` returns an object when outside of test.php but NULL when inside of it.

Comment: See my edit. Fixed but dont know why.

Comment: It's up to you, but I think you *really* should consider tracking this down and not consider the issue fixed.  If $session is out of scope of test.php, there's got to be a reason why. Given what you had coded originally, it should work, and the fact that it's not means that something odd is going on that could cause you much grief and strife later.  If you're willing to continue troubleshooting, I have another idea or two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$session` is not in the scope. include that script where you have initialized $session. or declare it as global in all scripts that will save the include just for $session. why not use `$_SESSION` though?

Comment: Declared $session as global and had the same problem so it cant be a scope thing. I use `$_SESSION` for many different things in the $session object.

Answer (score -1):

Dumb question: Have you already require_once'd test.php somewhere else in your script? If so, then it's possible that $session may not have been set when you included it the first time. Have you tried include('test.php') instead?

**DEBUGGING EDIT:**

You can validate the order things are being called in by trying the following:

In the caller.php (or whatever you call it) file:

```
echo "Debug 1";
echo $session->name;
require_once('test.php');
```

In test.php:

```
echo "Debug 2";
var_dump($session->name);
```

Which is printed first, Debug 1 or Debug 2?

Comment: Haven't required test.php anywhere else. $session instance is created right before I do anything else.

Comment: To whomever downvoted this: And this was downvoted why, exactly? It's pretty prickish to downvote an answer without any kind of reason why you think that this couldn't possibly be the right answer. I'm sitting here with a couple of test files that, according to the OP's original specs, duplicate what he's describing precisely because of a doubled require_once.

Comment: Debug 1, which dumps the object, then Debug 2, which is NULL

Comment: Are there any functions at play here?  In particular, is the var_dump() call within test.php within a function?  Is there anything in test.php other than the var_dump() call?

Comment: No functions. Yes other stuff in test.php but isnt bothering anything. Tried it with only var_dump(), same result

Comment: What do you get in the first file if you do a var_dump($session)?  Also, it's a bit weird that the second file is giving you back NULL; if $session were really out of scope, you wouldn't get NULL, you'd get a property of non-object error.  Can you give any details about the class that $session is an instance of?  I can think of some contrived situations where it might return one thing in one file and another in another, but it would be really strange.